# Post data by curl dont work but html fine

Tags: php, html, curl

i in html :

```
<form action="address" method="post" id="login_form">
    <input type="text" class="text-input captcha-input" id="captcha_input" name="captcha"/>            
    <input class="button" type="submit" id="submit" value="Sign In">
</form>
```

and all fine
But in Curl

```
$ch = curl_init( $url );
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, 'captcha=dawdewad');
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
echo $response = curl_exec( $ch );
curl_close($ch);
```

dont post captcha !
help me plz

Comment: Why do you think it's not posting the captcha?

Comment: Are you getting any errors?  After `curl_exec($ch)` do `var_dump(curl_getinfo($ch));` and post the results

Comment: i send 'captcha =dawdewad&user=11&pass=22' error says : user OK ,pass Ok ,but captcha don't set ! in html work fine .return result JSON format .

Comment: result on two posts :
array(20) {
  ["url"]=>
  string(46) "siteAddressUrl"
  ["content_type"]=>
  string(9) "text/html"
  ["http_code"]=>
  int(200)
  ["header_size"]=>
  int(635)
  ["request_size"]=>
  int(207)
  ["filetime"]=>
  int(-1)
  ["ssl_verify_result"]=>
  int(0)
  ["redirect_count"]=>
  int(0)
  ["total_time"]=>
  float(1.06)
  ["namelookup_time"]=>
  float(0)
  ["connect_time"]=>
  float(0.015)
  ["pretransfer_time"]=>
  float(0.015)
  ["size_upload"]=>

Comment: float(252)
  ["size_download"]=>
  float(111)
  ["speed_download"]=>
  float(104)
  ["speed_upload"]=>
  float(237)
  ["download_content_length"]=>
  float(111)
  ["upload_content_length"]=>
  float(252)
  ["starttransfer_time"]=>
  float(0.686)
  ["redirect_time"]=>
  float(0)
}